# How to solve this error in Ionic template chatRoom?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, sass

I created a room messaging chat with ionic angular , all work fine but i have a problem in messages rows
for messages of others users , the row work fine all the columns show in same row but for my Msgs the logo is showing on the top as first row and rest of msg showing in a second row, where is the problem ? , [image]

my chat page.html :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Chat</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button fill="clear" (click)="signOut()">
        <ion-icon name="log-out" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="ion-padding">

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let message of messages ">

      <ion-col size="3" *ngIf="message.myMsg">
        <img [src]="message.userphoto" class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="50">
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="9" class="message" [offset]="message.myMsg ? 3 : 0"
        [ngClass]="{ 'my-message': message.myMsg, 'other-message': !message.myMsg }">
        <b style="color: black;">{{ message.fromName }}</b> <img style="margin-left:5px;width:17px;"
          src="assets/antenna.png" alt="" srcset=""><br>
        <span>{{ message.msg }}
        </span>


        <div class="time ion-text-right"><br>{{ message.createdAt?.toMillis() | date:'short' }}</div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="3" *ngIf="!message.myMsg">
        <img [src]="message.userphoto" class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="50">
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>



</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
      <ion-col size="10">
        <ion-textarea style="color:black;border-radius: 5%;" placeholder="Aa" autoGrow="true" class="message-input"
          rows="1" maxLength="500" [(ngModel)]="newMsg">
        </ion-textarea>
      </ion-col>


      <ion-col size="2">

        <ion-button icon-only item-right (click)="sendMessage()" color="light">
          <ion-icon color="primary" name="send"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

and my Css :

```
ion-content {
   
    --background: url('/assets/chatbg.jpg') 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
.message-input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid var(--ion-color-medium);
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    resize: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    --padding-start: 8px;
}
 
.message {
    padding: 10px !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    margin-bottom: 4px !important;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
 
.my-message {
    background:  var(--ion-color-primary);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20%;
}
 
.other-message {
    background:  lightgray;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 20%;
}
 
.time {
    color: #dfdfdf;
    float: right;
    font-size: small;
}
```

my ts page :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ChatService } from '../chat.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { finalize, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
export interface FILE {
  name: string;
  filepath: string;
  size: number;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.page.scss'],
})


export class ChatPage implements OnInit {
  ngFireUploadTask: AngularFireUploadTask;

  progressNum: Observable<number>;

  progressSnapshot: Observable<any>;

  fileUploadedPath: Observable<string>;
  room: any;
  files: Observable<FILE[]>;
  ImgtoSend: any;
  FileName: string;
  FileSize: number;
  photo: string;
  isImgUploading: boolean;
  isImgUploaded: boolean;
  photos: any = [];
  private ngFirestoreCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<FILE>;


  @ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;

  messages: any = [];
  newMsg = '';
  users: any = [];
  constructor(private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
    private angularFireStorage: AngularFireStorage, private chatService: ChatService, private router: Router) {
    this.isImgUploading = false;
    this.isImgUploaded = false;

    this.ngFirestoreCollection = angularFirestore.collection<FILE>('filesCollection');
    this.files = this.ngFirestoreCollection.valueChanges();

  }

  async ngOnInit() {


    return (await this.chatService.getChatMessages()).subscribe(res => {
      this.messages = res.filter(a => a.fromName != "Deleted");
      this.messages.forEach(m => {
        console.log(m.from);
      });
    }
    );



  }

  getphotoOfUsers(uid) {
    console.log(uid);
    return this.chatService.getUsers().then(res => {
      res.subscribe(result => {
        this.photo = result.filter(a => a.uid == uid).map(a => a.photo).toString();
        console.log("photo" + this.photo);

      }
      )
    }
    )
  }
  sendMessage() {

    this.chatService.getUsers().then(res => {
      res.subscribe(result => {
        this.photo = result.filter(a => a.uid == this.chatService.currentUser.uid).map(a => a.photo).toString();
        console.log("photo" + this.photo);
        this.chatService.addChatMessage(this.newMsg, this.photo).then(() => {
          this.newMsg = '';
          this.content.scrollToBottom();
        });
      }
      )
    });

  }










}
```

Comment: For starters, the ionic grid system has only 12 columns.  You have defined your columns as 3 + 9 + 3 = 15.

Comment: but , the two column with size 3 are defined in IF statement , one of them can be executed not both

Answer (score 0):

after removing offset [offset]="message.myMsg ? 3 : 0"  , all work fine